# Python scraping - Table with a more than one text element

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Python noob here. This is my first ever python code. I am trying to scrape the list of Instagram accounts and their followers from this [website](https://www.trackalytics.com/the-most-followed-instagram-profiles/page/1/). I am able to extract the data but I am having a hard time getting it in a correct format in a CSV. I want to extract the data with the headers Instagram Handle, Followers, Posts for all the pages on this website. Here is my code, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.trackalytics.com/the-most-followed-instagram-profiles/page/1/'

headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url)


r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

table2 = soup.find_all('table', recursive=True)

table = table2[0]

with open ("instagram.txt", 'w') as file:
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
     for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        container = cell.text.strip()
        file.write(container)
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: if you want to create CSV file then better use module `csv` to do it. Using only normal `open()` you may create incorrect CSV file. You can't use `file.write(container)` to create correct row in CSV. You have to join all elements on list using `","` to create single string and then write it. But using module `csv` you can use `csv_writer.writerow(list)` and it will automatically convert list to correct string.

Comment: BTW: to get better data in CSV you may have to create more complex code which gets only some part from cell and skip other elements (ie. skip useless button), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you should use module `csv` to create correct CSV file. Using only normal `open()` and `write()` you have to manually convert every row of data to string with values separated by `,` and with `\n` at the end. But it may need other more complex changes - ie. put text in `" "` if there is `,` or `\n` in text.

Second: you may need more complex code to clean data before saving - ie. you could remove spaces, tabs, `\n`, `( )`, split some text into two columns, etc.

Third: you may need loop to read other pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# --- functions ---

def get_page(number):
    url = 'https://www.trackalytics.com/the-most-followed-instagram-profiles/page/{}/'.format(number)
    headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    return soup

def get_data(soup):
    table = soup.find('table')

    results = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        all_cells = row.find_all('td')

        # skip empty rows
        if all_cells:
            a = all_cells[0].find('span').text.strip()

            b = all_cells[1].text.strip()

            c = all_cells[2].text.strip().split('\n')
            c = [clean(item) for item in c]

            d = all_cells[3].text.strip().split('\n')
            d = [clean(item) for item in d]

            e = all_cells[3].text.strip().split('\n')
            e = [clean(item) for item in e]

            f = all_cells[3].text.strip().split('\n')
            f = [clean(item) for item in f]

            results.append([a,b,c[0],c[1],d[0],d[1],e[0],e[1],f[0],f[1]])

    return results

def clean(text):
    return text.strip().replace(' ', '').replace(',', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')

def write_data(data):

    with open ("instagram.txt", 'w') as writer:
        cvs_writer = csv.writer(writer)

        # write header
        cvs_writer.writerow([
            'Rank',
            'Profile',
            'Total Followers',
            'Total Followers today',
            'Total Following',
            'Total Following today',
            'Total Posts',
            'Total Posts today',
            'Total Influence',
            'Total Influence today'
        ])

        cvs_writer.writerows(data)

# --- main ---

all_data = []

for number in range(1, 10):
    print('page:', number)
    soup = get_page(number)
    data = get_data(soup)
    all_data.extend(data)

write_data(all_data)
```

Comment: Simple explanation and beautifully written code. It worked perfectly, and I learnt so much from this answer. Thanks for taking a look at this. You are a gentleman and a scholar!